# Where I set the resolution to enter on tablet with mobile theme?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress theme with mobile version. But when I get on tablets display me web version, where I set the resolution to enter the mobile version when you get on the tablet?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with changing theme breakpoints is that every theme sets them up differently so there is no general solution, however you can be pointed in the right direction.

The easiest way to track down exactly where your mobile breakpoints are coming from is to reduce your browser to a mobile size and use your developer tools to inspect resized elements. Select an element and look in the inspector for media query applied styles, you should see something like this:

[image]

In the picture example, app-23587ee9.css is the name of the CSS file the query is located and 412 is the line number (this example is from my website, in which case this is actually a compiled, versioned CSS file that's generated by Gulp but most themes still use standard CSS).

Track down the css file, skip down to the line number and you should see media queries with a max-width that breaks at mobile screen sizes (probably 320px or 480px). What you'll need to do is extend that number to cover tablet screen sizes via search and replace.

There is a good reference at [CSS Tips](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for resolutions for standard devices, open the tablet accordion item and select iPad. It's up to you whether or not you want to target (up to) landscape or portrait, if portrait replace your mobile breakpoint with 768px and if landscape set it to 1024px.

One thing to keep in mind is that these days media query breakpoints can get pretty complicated, we're now dealing with retina screens and phones with natively larger resolutions than we used to so have a good read through that page from CSS Tips to get a better idea of what you want to set your breakpoint to.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8r9m4dry7sv71my/custom.css?dl=0 this is my code from theme and mobile css are https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpoodvt40apr7a8/main.css?dl=0

Comment: @MoraruVladut check line 3245, I've never seen max height used before in a media query but I believe if you remove that and change 800px to 1024px you should be in business.

Comment: wait a sec, to format css in beuty css, i`m note shure if talking about the same line

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyl2agsqo0lh0ji/Desktop.rar?dl=0 here is organise code, please read now

Comment: @MoraruVladut why is it in a RAR file?

Comment: I change now, is two files, from mobile theme and web

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8r9m4dry7sv71my/custom.css?dl=0 WEB and mobile theme https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpoodvt40apr7a8/main.css?dl=0 css

Comment: @MoraruVladut check your custom.css file from line 6620 down, it looks like most of your breakpoints are set to tablet portrait so it's just a matter of increasing those to cover landscape sizes.

Comment: @media (max-width: 750px) {
    .open-block .open-date .date-list li {
        padding-left: 24px;
        padding-right: 24px
    }
} i change max-width with 1024?

Comment: @MoraruVladut yes, along with anything else other styles you'd like applied on the larger screen resolution.

Comment: This tool helps you finding your breakpoints and displays them side by side http://ponyframe.com/breakpoints?url=smashingmagazine.com (enter your url at the top)